# Restoring selective tables from an entire database dump?

Tags: mysql, database-restore

I have a mysql dump created with mysqldump that holds all the tables in my database and all their data. However I only want to restore two tables. (lets call them `kittens` and `kittens_votes`)

How would I restore those two tables without restoring the entire database?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you have three main options.

1. You can manually find the SQL statements in the file relating to the backed up tables and copy them manually.  This has the advantage of being simple, but for large backups it's impractical.
2. Restore the database to a temporary database.  Basically, create a new db, restore it to that db, and then copy the data from there to the old one.  This will work well only if you're doing single database backups (If there's no `CREATE DATABASE` command(s) in the backup file).
3. Restore the database to a new database server, and copy from there.  This works well if you take full server backups as opposed to single database backups.

Which one you choose will depend upon the exact situation (including how much data you have)...

Comment: I was afraid that I'd have to do that, I did option #2

Answer (score 1):

You can parse out `CREATE TABLE kittens|kitten_votes` AND `INSERT INTO ...` using regexp, for example, and only execute these statements. As far as I know, there's no other way to "partially restore" from dump.

Answer (score 1):

Open the .sql file and copy the insert statements for the tables you want.

Comment: I only have commandline access to the server where the dump is, so that might be a bit difficult

Comment: This could be unbearable if dump is multigigabyte.

Answer (score 0):

create a new user with access to only those 2 tables. Now restore the DB with -f (force) option that will ignore the failed statements and execute only those statements it has permission to.

Answer (score 0):

What you want is a "Single Table Restore"

http://hashmysql.org/wiki/Single_table_restore

A few options are outlined above ... However the one which worked for me was:

- Create a new DB

> $ mysql -u root -p CREATE DATABASE temp_db

- Insert the .sql file ( the one with the desired table ) into the new DB

> $ mysql -u root -p temp_db < ~/full/path/to/your_database_file.sql

- dump the desired table

> $ mysqldump -u root -p temp_db awesome_single_table > ~/awesome_single_table.sql

- import desired table

> $ mysql -u root -p original_database < ~/awesome_single_table.sql

Then delete the temp_db and you're all golden!